# Upgrade pip on QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Can I upgrade `pip` on QGIS? if yes, How to do this? like this one:

```
def install(package): 
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'): 
        pip.main(['install', package]) 
    else: 
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])
```

Answer (score 1):

of course you can update it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223296/4699904 , but if you update pip from qgis console it will close, you need to do it from outside of qgis environment

To install some package and check the PIP version you can try something like this:

```
def install_pip_requirements(package):
''' Install Requeriments from pip '''
try:
    import pip
except ImportError:
    #whatever 
    raise
try:
    if float(pip.__version__) <= 10:
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        from pip._internal import main
        main(['install', package])
except Exception:
    raise
return
```